# How to join two mysql table and retrieve latest results from joined table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. I need to join these two tables and retrieve latest status from execution table. How can I retrieve?

My schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
    (`id` serial primary key, `ref_id` int, `ref_name` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO test 
    (`id`, `ref_id`, `ref_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'trial'),
    (2, 3, 'test'),
    (3, 7, 'testing')
;


CREATE TABLE execution 
    (`id` serial primary key, `ref_id` int, `status` varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO execution 
    (`id`, `ref_id`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Completed'),
    (2, 2, 'Completed'),
    (3, 1, 'Completed'),
    (4, 3, 'In progress'),
    (5, 3, 'To do'),
    (6, 2, 'In progress'),
    (7, 1, 'Completed'),
    (7, 1, 'To do')
;
```

Expected result is here below.

```
ref_id | ref_name | status      |
3      | testing  | In progress |
2      | test     | To do       |
1      | trial    | To do       |
```

I have tried with below query:

```
SELECT
    ref_id, 
    ref_name, 
    status 
FROM 
    test 
    JOIN execution ON test.ref_id = execution.ref_id 
GROUP BY `ref_id` 
ORDER BY `ref_id` DESC;
```

This query retrieves the `status`, but the retrieved `status` is not a latest one. How can retrieve the latest status by *joining* these two tables.

Comment: I've fixed it this time, but for next time, please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is the order of your status?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  below query

```
select T2.ref_id,T2.ref_name,OE.status from
   (
   select t1.ref_id,t1.ref_name,e.id from test t1 inner join

    (select max(id) as id,ref_id  from execution group by ref_id) as e
    on
    t1.ref_id=e.ref_id
   ) as T2
inner join execution OE on T2.id=OE.id
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rvnm8APX27dmW9a84JkCsS/1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have given in-correct data as an example as ref_id 7 not found in 
execution table. However this might help you

```
SELECT b.ref_id,
b.ref_name,
a.status
FROM execution a
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id ,ref_id
      FROM execution 
      GROUP BY ref_id) a1
USING(id,ref_id)
JOIN test b ON a.ref_id = b.ref_id ORDER BY ref_id DESC;
```